# Making an rest api call from angular 9 service class

Tags: angular, rest

I have written an Api as part of a coding exercise and am testing it in Postman as below. I'm content with how this works for now.

[image]

So now I'm wanting to call it from an Angular 9 project and I've written a service with code below but don't know how to assign the three parameters to the parameter 'model'

This is my service class

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CalcService {

  baseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api/Calculator/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  calculate(model: any) {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl, model)
      .pipe(map((response: any) => {
        const val = response;
      }));
  }

}
```

This is my component, and I'm wanting to call the service within getAnswerFromApi() but am not sure how to assign the three parameters

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CalcService } from '../_services/calc.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calculator',
  templateUrl: './calculator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calculator.component.css']
})
export class CalculatorComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Ofgem Calculator';

  model: any = {};

  subText = ''; // The text that should appear in the sub-display
  mainText = ''; // The text that should appear in the main display
  firstNumber: number; // The first operand
  secondNumber: number; // The second operand
  operator = ''; // The operator
  calculationString = '';
  // This is the string that denotes the operation being performed
  answered = false;
  operatorSet = false;

  answer = '';

  constructor(private calcService: CalcService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  pressKey(key: string) {
    if (key === '/' || key === 'x' || key === '-' || key === '+') {
       const lastKey = this.mainText[this.mainText.length - 1];
       if (lastKey === '/' || lastKey === 'x' || lastKey === '-' || lastKey === '+')  {
         this.operatorSet = true;
       }
       if ((this.operatorSet) || (this.mainText === '')) {
         return;
       }
       this.firstNumber = parseFloat(this.mainText);
       this.operator = key;
       this.operatorSet = true;
    }
    if (this.mainText.length === 10) {
      return;
    }
    this.mainText += key;
 }

 getAnswerFromApi() {
   this.calculationString = this.mainText;
   this.secondNumber = parseFloat(this.mainText.split(this.operator)[1]);

   this.calcService.calculate(this.model).subscribe(next => {
     console.log('did calc');
   }, error => {
     console.log('failed calc');
   });

 }
  allClear() {
    this.subText = '';
    this.mainText = '';
    this.operator = '';
    this.calculationString = '';
    this.answered = false;
    this.operatorSet = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: One issue is that your use of RxJS map operator isn’t returning anything. You need to return something from within that map that you expect to get in your subscribe success handler. Or just not use map at all if you don’t need any transformation on the steam of data.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderStaroselsky although my question was more about calling calcService.calculate and assigning parameters. Can you give me an example of what you mean about the map?

Comment: Inside your service where you make the http client get call, you are using map operator. map expects you to return something, anything. In your code you setting a variable called val but not actually return it. Either return val or just remove pipe and map entirely.

Comment: calculate(model: any) {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl, model)
      .pipe(map((response: any) => {
        const val = response;
        `return val;`
      }));
  }

You need to return your value in your pipe which is located in calcService

Answer (score 0):

this is how to do it

```
// service file

 .....    

calculate() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl)
  }

......

// component ts file

getAnswerFromApi() {
   ....

   this.calcService.calculate()
    .subscribe((next : any) => {
     this.model = next;
   }, error => {
     console.log('failed calc', error);
   });

 }
```

Comment: How do I assign parameters to ````this.model````?

Comment: what parameters?

Comment: if the response data is eg { name: "Will", _id: "1" }

doing this 

   this.calcService.calculate()
    .subscribe((next : any) => {
     this.model = next;
   }, error => {
     console.log('failed calc', error);
   });

makes this.model = { name: "Will", _id: "1" }

Comment: if you want to send query parameters from your component.ts when making the request then you can do something like this 

component.ts

let = data = { page: 1, pageSize: 10 }

this.calcService.calculate(data)

service.ts

calculate(payload) {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl, { parmas: payload })
  }

so the url will look like this https://example.com/?page=1&pageSize=10